# Rc<RefCell<Value>> Error method not found in `&mut Rc<RefCell<Node>>`

Tags: rust, refcell

I am havin issues working with Rc and RefCell. when I call a function that exists in the Contained Struct, the compiler complains the method 'add_child' is not found.

When I fun the below code I get the error

```
  x.add_edge(jfk);    |    ^^^^^^^^ method not found in `&mut Rc<RefCell<Node>>
```

Directory structure:

```
       /graph
          /node.rs
          /mod.rs
        main.rs
```

`main.rs`

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
fn main() {
    let dfw = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(1)));
    let jfk = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node::new(2)));

    dfw.borrow_mut().add_child(jfk) // -> This method call causes the error
}
```

`graph/node.rs`

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node {
    pub id: u32,
    pub children: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}

impl Node {
    pub fn add_child(&mut self, node: Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
        self.children.push(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have method `add_child `, but you are calling `add_edge`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM no thats not the issue, I just updated the name for clarity. the error is still there

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. [This works.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3d58afb775944dac5a76f5ee9902222b)

Comment: @AurelBílý It seems like the issue is only in main, i tried to reproduce it the moving the code in main to the same file as where Node is declared and it works. so not sure why the function is not accessible outside the module since it is public

Answer (score 0):

The `main.rs` was importing

```
use std::borrow::BorrowMut;
```

Removing this line fixed it.